# Database query simplification of WHERE clause over multple rows

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a change to simplify this database query (which must be run many times per request) maybe with an IN clause or something else?

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `columnname1` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname2` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname3` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname4` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname5` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname6` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname7` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname8` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname9` = "longer-value" OR
      `columnname10` = "longer-value"
```

Please note that this query checks for that value over 10 different columns.

Comment: You forgot to normalise your database.

Comment: `(which must be run many times per request)` That's a red flag. Can you reduce the number of queries? Perhaps with a `JOIN`?

Comment: Is there a good reason that you cannot break this into two normalized tables?  I have been in said situation before where a full table scan was a lot faster than a normalized lookup... BUT it is rare.

Comment: `rownameX` should be `columnnameX`, shouldn't it?

Comment: And you mean it *"checks for that value over 10 different **columns** (not rows)."* Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have actually done this before...

```
WHERE "longer-value" IN (`rowname1`, `rowname2`, ... , `rownameN`)
```

Comment: I think you mistaking, Are you sure you can do it? did you notice that the rowname are differnt columns.

Comment: @DorCohen: it works with fields or values in the IN... It's syntax sugar for a bunch of `a = 10 OR b = 10 OR c = 10`.